# Best Platform to build Business Directory Website ,which is SEO friendly?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, business-models

We have plan to setup a business directory website. and our team thinking of suitable platform

Php or ASP  i want to know which is most commonly used in Commercial Business Directory Websites.  How does Business Directory Websites get their pages indexed so fast , does we consider creating website just like Blog / forums   which index's faster than static Website .

How business Directory Website works ....??

Answer (score 1):

- Both PHP and ASP .NET MVC are good choices to wrote a business directory with.
- The platform you choose will not affect how the pages are indexed.
- Php is probably the most commonly used because it has loads of free tools and free OS like linux.
- The important thing is what you are already familiar with. Cost of hardware software, Using the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question - creation of a sitemap will indicate to search engines how often you update your pages. If your site has a good ranking, and the pages change as often as you say they will, then they will check them often and update their indexes.